# SELECT SQL no funciona

Tags: java, sql

estoy trabajando en Java con un PreparedStatement. Lo que quiero hacer es una simple comprobación, en la que si el SELECT me devuelve un resultado hago una cosa, y en caso de que no devuelva nada, creo una instancia de la tabla en cuestión y sigo con la ejecución (en el código que dejo más adelante se ve mejor). Mi problema está en que, cuando no existe lo que busco en la BD, lo creo y vuelvo a consultar si existe (compruebo previamente que sí se creo correctamente mirando en la BD manualmente) y me dice que no existe. Os dejo código a continuación:

```
sentencia = (CallableStatement) entry_conn.prepareCall("{call newLote(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
                    
                    sentencia.setInt("feeds_expedientes", feeds_expedientes);
                    
                    sentencia.setInt("numero_de_lote", ppl[i].getID());
                    sentencia.setString("objeto", ppl[i].getProcurementProject().getName());
                    sentencia.setDouble("importe_sin_impuestos", ppl[i].getProcurementProject().getBudgetAmount().getTotalAmount());
                    sentencia.setDouble("importe_con_impuestos", ppl[i].getProcurementProject().getBudgetAmount().getTaxExclusiveAmount());
                    
                    // Para el lugar de ejecución primero miramos si existe, si no existe lo creamos
                    sentencia_busqueda = entry_conn.prepareStatement("SELECT lugar_de_ejecucion FROM tbl_lugar_de_ejecucion WHERE pais = ? AND" 
                            + " calle = ? AND codigo_postal = ? AND poblacion = ?");
                    
                    if (ppl[i].getProcurementProject().getRealizedLocation().getAddress().getCountry().getName() != null){
                        String pais = ppl[i].getProcurementProject().getRealizedLocation().getAddress().getCountry().getName();
                        sentencia_busqueda.setString(1, pais);
                    }else{
                        sentencia_busqueda.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.NULL);
                    }
                    
                    if (ppl[i].getProcurementProject().getRealizedLocation().getAddress().getAddressLine() != null){
                        String calle = ppl[i].getProcurementProject().getRealizedLocation().getAddress().getAddressLine().getLine();
                        sentencia_busqueda.setString(2, calle);
                    }else{
                        sentencia_busqueda.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.NULL);
                    }
                    
                    if (ppl[i].getProcurementProject().getRealizedLocation().getAddress().getPostalZone() != null){
                        String codigo_postal = ppl[i].getProcurementProject().getRealizedLocation().getAddress().getPostalZone();
                        sentencia_busqueda.setString(3, codigo_postal);
                    }else{
                        sentencia_busqueda.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.NULL);
                    }
                    
                    if (ppl[i].getProcurementProject().getRealizedLocation().getAddress().getCityName() != null){
                        String poblacion = ppl[i].getProcurementProject().getRealizedLocation().getAddress().getCityName();
                        sentencia_busqueda.setString(4, poblacion);
                    }else{
                        sentencia_busqueda.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.NULL);
                    }
                    
                    System.out.println(sentencia_busqueda);
                    
                    ResultSet rs = sentencia_busqueda.executeQuery();

                    if (rs.next()){
                        sentencia.setInt("lugar_de_ejecucion", rs.getInt("lugar_de_ejecucion"));
                    }else{
                        writeLugarDeEjecucion_Lote(ppl[i].getProcurementProject(), entry_conn);
                        
                        System.out.println(sentencia_busqueda);
                        
                        rs = sentencia_busqueda.executeQuery();
                        if(rs.next()){
                            sentencia.setInt("lugar_de_ejecucion", rs.getInt("lugar_de_ejecucion"));
                        }
                    }
                    
                    sentencia.execute();
                    
                    lote = sentencia.getInt("lote");
                    
                    sentencia.close();
```

Al entrar por el else se crea la fila en la BD para lugar_de_ejecucion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero al hacer la siguiente Query, que queda tal que:

> SELECT * FROM tbl_lugar_de_ejecucion WHERE pais = 'España' AND calle = null AND codigo_postal = null AND poblacion = null

No lo encuentra.

Agradezco cualquier idea de qué estoy haciendo mal. Gracias.

Comment: Es probable que tengas un error en la consulta SQL ya que normalmente cuando quieres comprobar si un valor es NULL tienes que poner, por ejemplo: `pais IS NULL` y no `pais = NULL`

Comment: Si puede ser que sea eso, probaré. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Es exactamente como te dicen en los comentarios, lo explicaré como respuesta.

En SQL es imposible usar los comparadores: `=, <, >, <=, >=, <>`, cuando hablamos de comparar valores `NULL`.

En vez de ello, usamos los operadores `IS NULL` o `IS NOT NULL`.

EN resumidas cuentas, tu query quedaría del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_lugar_de_ejecucion 
WHERE pais = 'España' 
AND calle IS NULL
AND codigo_postal IS NULL
AND poblacion IS NULL
```

Cabe aclarar, que esta query funciona si es que las 3 columnas son NULL.
Es decir, si quisieras evaluar que solo 1 columna vacía, o encontrar más columnas vacías, podrías cambiar los AND del WHERE, y usar OR, en caso de buscar todas las columnas vacías.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Tu problema está en el tratamiento de los valores `null`, debes escribir la sentencia de manera que puedas encontrar un registro aunque tenga valores `null`, por ejemplo, valiéndote de la función `coalesce`:

```sql
SELECT lugar_de_ejecucion 
  FROM tbl_lugar_de_ejecucion 
 WHERE coalesce(pais, '') = ? 
   AND coalesce(calle, '') = ? 
   AND coalesce(codigo_postal, '') = ? 
   AND coalesce(poblacion, '') = ?
```

Si escribes la sentencia de esta manera, envía una cadena en blanco cuando ahora envías un `null`, por ejemplo:

```java
String pais = '';
if (ppl[i].getProcurementProject().getRealizedLocation().getAddress().getCountry().getName() != null){
  pais = ppl[i].getProcurementProject().getRealizedLocation().getAddress().getCountry().getName();
}
sentencia_busqueda.setString(1, pais);
```

Si quieres saber por qué esto resuelve el problema, continúa leyendo, veamos algo de teoría.

## El valor `null` en SQL

En SQL `null` es un valor especial y hay ocasiones en las que no se *trata* igual que otros valores, debes recordar primero que:

##### `null` significa desconocido o indeterminado.

Esto tiene varias implicaciones.

### Operadores de comparación

Y los operadores de comparación, que en otros lenguajes suelen devolver valores `true` y `false`, en SQL además pueden devolver el valor `null`, la lógica es simple, pero debes entenderla.

Por ejemplo, si tienes la comparación: `5 > 4`, el operador devuelve `true`, si tienes `4 > 5` el operador devuelve `false`, pero si tienes `null > 4` o `5 > null`, ya que `null` es `desconocido`, no puedes decir cuál es mayor (hasta que el número se conozca), por lo tanto, el resultado es también desconocido, o sea, `null`.

Esto funciona de la misma manera con todos los operadores, incluyendo el operador de igualdad. Si tienes la comparación `'España' = 'España'`, devuelve `true`, si tienes `'España' = 'Italia'` devuelve `false`, pero si tienes `'España' = null`, devuelve `null`, ya que se desconoce si son iguales.

Por esta misma razón, `null = null`, no puede devolver verdadero. No tenemos forma de saber si un valor desconocido es igual a otro valor desconocido, simplemente no lo sabemos, y por eso `null = null` devuelve `null`.

Por esta razón, existe el operador *especial* `is null`, que nos sirve cuando queremos evaluar si un determinado valor *es `null`*. Este operador solamente devuelve `true` o `false` según sea el caso.

### Tablas de verdad

Entonces, las tablas de verdad, consideran el valor `null`, y quedan así:

| p | q | not p | p and q | p or q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| true | true | false | true | true |
| true | false | false | false | true |
| true | null | false | null | true |
| false | true | true | false | true |
| false | false | true | false | false |
| false | null | true | false | null |
| null | true | null | null | true |
| null | false | null | false | null |
| null | null | null | null | null |

### Cláusula where

Para que un registro sea incluido en el conjunto de resultados, el cómputo total de la sentencia `where` debe devolver `true`. Los registros que devuelvan `false` y los que devuelvan `null` son excluidos de los resultados de la consulta.

Como puedes ver en la tabla de verdad, en tu consulta el `where` es una expresión compuesta por una serie de expresiones de comparación *conectadas* por el operador lógico `and`.

Basta con que  una comparación devuelva `null` para que toda la expresión devuelva `null`.

### La función `coalesce()`

Coalesce es una función que toma 2 o más parámetros y devuelve el valor del primer parámetro no nulo, evaluándolos en el orden en el que le son dados.

- `coalesce('juan', 'pedro')` devuelve `'juan'`
- `coalesce(null, null, 'pedro', 'josé')` devuelve `'pedro'`

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas, efectivamente era la comparación en SQL, cambiando **x = null** por **x is null**.